# Delete not working in Linq to sql using Jquery?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

//        Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(Int32 id)
{
                    // TODO: Add delete logic here
        TendorList t1 = db.TendorLists.Where(x => x.CompanyId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        db.TendorLists.DeleteOnSubmit(t1);
        db.SubmitChanges();``
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

//    Jquery Code

```
$("body").on("click", "#tblStudent .Delete", function () {
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete this row?")) {`enter code here`
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var CompanyId = row.find("span").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Tendor/Delete",
                data: '{CompanyId: ' + CompanyId + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    row.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have more information than "not working"? Exceptions? Console errors? Debugging info?

Comment: You are passing a complex object but your controller is accepting an `int`. You might just want to put the id in the route, or you can create an object with a CompanyId property and take that as an argument to the controller instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You send the id as CompanyId, but in code behind you try to catch it as Id.
you should update your post data as data: '{id: ' + CompanyId + '}',